# Question about Berkeley Data Structures Free Online Course (CS61B) Tutorial question on static variables in Java

Tags: java, constructor, static

Note: This is not a homework assignment, but a free course that anyone can access.
The course can be found at: https://sp18.datastructur.es/index.html
The tutorial question can be found at: https://sp18.datastructur.es/materials/discussion/examprep02sol.pdf

Also, the variables are named as such in order to confuse potential students, and I decided not to change it for fear of changing the code resulting in a different output. Also, some of the variables (baby), and method calls were not used at all, but I have retained it in order to keep to the original question.

**Q1 Write what the main method will print out once it is executed. It might be helpful to draw box and pointer diagrams to keep track of variables (Spring ’15, MT1)**

```
public class Shock {
    public static int bang;
    public static Shock baby;

    public Shock() {
        this.bang = 100;
    }

    public Shock(int num) {
        this.bang = num;
        baby = starter();
        this.bang += num;
    }

    public static Shock starter() {
        Shock gear = new Shock();
        return gear;
    }

    public static void shrink(Shock statik) {
        statik.bang -= 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shock gear = new Shock(200);
        System.out.println(gear.bang); //300
        shrink(gear);
        shrink(starter());
        System.out.println(gear.bang); //99
    }
}
```

Why is the value of gear.bang 300 instead of 200 + 200? I understand that gear is a static variable, but when using the second constructor, the value 100 should not have been involved at all. I would have thought that the static variable bang would be set as 200, then 200 += 200 will result in the static variable bang being 400 for all instances of Shock class. Why is gear.bang 300 instead?

Comment: As JB Nizet pointed it out, just follow a flow... You set bang to 200 by creating new Shock object using data constructor, then create another Shock object with empty constructor which sets your bang to 100, then add 200 by calling this.bang += num; -> bang = 100+200; This is all possible because bang is static!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second constructor calls `starter()`.

`starter()` calls `new Shock()`.

The `Shock()` constructor sets bang to 100. Then 200 is added to bang. So bang is 300.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that. This means that any method call to starter() would set the static variable bang to 100 right? I see. Thank you!